# Dynamical obstructions for a vector field whose derivation sends an orthonormal set to a mutually Sasakian orthogonal vectors

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems

We ask two related questions which are inspired by this MO question [Does $P_xP_y+Q_xQ_y=0 \implies$ "NONEXISTENCE OF LIMIT CYCLE for $P\partial_x+Q\partial_y$"? (Complex Dilatation and Limit cycle Theory)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382577/does-p-xp-yq-xq-y-0-implies-nonexistence-of-limit-cycle-for-p-partial-xq)

1)Let $M$ be  a parallelizable manifold and $X$ be  a (non vanishing) vector field on $M$.
Is there a Riemannian metric $g$ on $M$, with associated Sasakian metric $g_S$ on $TM$, such that $DX:TM\to TTM$ carries a golabal orthonormal frame $V_1,V_2,\ldots,V_n$ to a mutually orthogonal set?

2)Let $(M,g)$ be  a parallelizable Riemannian  manifold  with associated Sasakian metric $g_S$ on $TM$. Assume that $X$ is   a (non vanishing) vector field on $M$.
Is there a golabal orthonormal  frame $W=\{V_1,V_2,\ldots,V_n\}$,  such that $DX:TM\to TTM$ carries $W$ to a mutually orthogonal set?

What kind of dynamical obstructions would appear?

**Remark:** As a  relation between the two questions of this post and its inspiring post   [Does $P_xP_y+Q_xQ_y=0 \implies$ "non-existence of limit cycle" for $P\partial_x+Q\partial_y$"? (Complex dilatation and limit cycle theory)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382577/does-p-xp-yq-xq-y-0-implies-nonexistence-of-limit-cycle-for-p-partial-xq)  we notice that every vector field $X=P\partial_x+Q\partial_y$ which satisfies $P_xP_y+Q_xQ_y=0$ then its derivative $DX:TR^2 \to TT \mathbb{R}^2 $ sends the standard orthonormal frame of $\mathbb{R}^2$ to a set of orthogonal vectores.

**Note:** By  parenthesized  word (non vanishing) mentioned in the above two questions, we would like to say:Our preference is a non vanishing vector field but  vanishing examples are also very appreciated.