# Dynamical obstructions for a vector field $X$ whose adjoint operator $ad_X$ sends a global orthonormal frame to a set of mutually orthogonal vectors

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems

1. Let $X$ be a vector field on a parallelizable manifold  $M$.
   Can we equipe $M$  with a Riemannian metric such that  we have at least one global orthonormal frame $\{V_1,V_2,\ldots,V_n \} $ such that $[X,V_i]$ is perpendicular to $[X,V_j]$ for  all $i\neq j$?
2. let $(M,g)$ be  a parallelizable  Riemannian manifold. Assume that $X$ is  a  vector field on $M$. Is there a  global orthonormal frame $\{V_1,V_2,\ldots,V_n \}$ with the property that $[X,V_i]$ is perpendicular to $[X,V_j]$ for  all $i\neq j$?

The above two questions are inspired by the following post, when we apply the conditions of these questions  to $X=P\partial_x+Q\partial_y$ and the global frame $\{\partial_x, \partial_y\}$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

[Does $P_xP_y+Q_xQ_y=0 \implies$ "NONEXISTENCE OF LIMIT CYCLE for $P\partial_x+Q\partial_y$"? (Complex Dilatation and Limit cycle Theory)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382577/does-p-xp-yq-xq-y-0-implies-nonexistence-of-limit-cycle-for-p-partial-xq)