# Is there a non geodesible vector field $P\partial_x+Q\partial_y$ which satisfies $P_xP_y+Q_xQ_y=0$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems

Inspired by the following two posts

[Finding a 1-form adapted to a smooth flow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/273635/36688)

[Does $P_xP_y+Q_xQ_y=0 \implies$ "non-existence of limit cycle" for $P\partial_x+Q\partial_y$"? (Complex dilatation and limit cycle theory)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382577/does-p-xp-yq-xq-y-0-implies-non-existence-of-limit-cycle-for-p-partial-x)

whose subjects are potentially related to limit cycle theory, we   ask the question below:

**Question:** Is there a vector field $X=P\partial_x +Q\partial_y$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ which satisfy $P_xP_y+Q_xQ_y=0$ but $X$ is not a geodesible vector field on $X\setminus S$ where $S$ is the set of singular points of $X$.

**Remark 1:** A geodesible vector field is a vector field $X$ which admit a  Riemannian metric $g$ on $X\setminus S$, the complement of its singular set, such that all non singular solution curves of $X$ are unparametrized geodesics with respect to metric $g$.

**Remark 2:** [There are two class of vector fields](https://mathoverflow.net/a/273648/36688) which lies in both class  "gedesible vector fields"  and "vector fields $X$ whose two columns of Jacobian matrix $JX$ are perpendicular to each other: The holomorphic one and $f(x)\partial_x+g(y)\partial_y$

Comment: What is the significance to the question of the Tolstoy quote in the bounty text?